# Code to write OutputStream into a file

Tags: java, file-io, io

I need to write some output into a file using Java. Currently my code is writing the OutputStream on system console. My concern is I have to write `process.getOutputStream()` output which returns an OutputStream instance.

```
final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
writer.println(200);
writer.close();
```

Comment: Hint: use [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). &nbsp;

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything?

Comment: Sorry to ask, what's this `process` variable?

Comment: Process is a java class.

Comment: @NPE :  you should have posted that as an answer.  It was more useful than the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("path/to/output-file.txt"));
```

It's just a matter of switching the output of the `PrintWriter` to the target you wish to use, a file in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help Oscar. But the concern as i mentioned i have to use constructor of PrintWriter which has to take process.getOutputStream(); not a file. Because I have to write the output of the process.getOutputStream.

Comment: You stated in the question: "I need to write some output into a file". If you write to `process.getOutputStream()`, that won't be a file, it will be the output stream of that process

Comment: What you probably intend to do, is _reading_ from the input stream of the process and _writing_ to the file using `PrintWriter`. By writing to `process.getOutputStream()` you'll write to the process' output stream.

Comment: @Oscar-- I have to write output of process.getOutputStream() to a file, and process.getOutputStream() returns an outputstream. Can I do that someway?

Comment: @user2254173 I believe you're confused, `process.getOutputStream()` is where you'd **write to** the process. The information that is **written by** the process must be retrieved using `process.getInputStream()`

Comment: The algorithm goes like this: you _read_ from the process' input stream, and then you _write_ what you just read to the output stream that's pointing to the file you want

Comment: I got your point. thank you so much Oscar. i will modify the code as per your suggetion to get into the file. thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

```
   BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( "output.txt"));
   write.write("your data");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense. A `ProcessOutputStream` isn't a file. It is a stream that is read by the process. What the process does with the data you send it is its business, not yours.

Comment: yet the title of the question did make sense.